# Disable menu link for certain languages

Tags: i18n-l10n, navigation, 9

I'm looking for a way to disable a single link in a menu for a certain language. From my understanding with similar issues, I'd like to activate translation for the menu link field *Enabled* since this is set for all languages by default.

[image]

Is there a way to activate the translation of this field for menu links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wasn't quite exactly what I was looking for, but it suits my case and is simple to use, so just in case anyone stumbles upon this looking for a solution:

The [Menu Manipulator module](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_manipulator) hides menu links that are pointing to contents without the current translation. You can specify which menus will be managed by this, so this is at least a little bit customizable.